# animate on activity no working in android

Tags: android, android-animation, draggable, slidingdrawer

I want to animate an activity transition when i click on an imageView,I have tried as belo,But it simply finish the activity and no animation works.So Please help me for this,If one can tell finish an activity like sliding drawer's handle,my code is as below,

**code**

```
menu.arrow.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                finish();
                overridePendingTransition(
                        R.anim.animated_activity_slide_bottom_in,
                        R.anim.animated_activity_slide_top_out);

            }
        });
```

Comment: see This http://android-er.blogspot.in/2013/04/custom-animation-while-switching.html

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar-I have changed as per this,Its not working..!!!

Comment: Post Full code I want to see code what u do

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in your AndroidManifest.xml the destination activity have:

**android:launchMode="singleInstance"**

try change to:

**android:launchMode="singleTask"**

Comment: But i want to finish activity not to navigate activity.

Comment: When you finish an activity, you return to the previous, so you override the default transition of. You can't show this transition if you have singleInstance. Try.